# Is it safe to distribute Google API credentials with apps?

Tags: node.js, http, security, electron, gmail-api

I'm trying to make a simple desktop email reader (w/ electron) that shows a user's emails on little cards that can be flipped through. Nothing much, that being why I don't want to setup a whole remote server system for it. I followed the instructions in [Google's NodeJS Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) to get started. That includes saving my Google API credentials to a file in the app. Upon login, a token is saved to disk. If no such token exists, it will open up a login page in the browser that redirects to `127.0.0.1:3000/authorize` (the express app running there saves the token). It works and doesn't require a remote server which is what I want.

**My question is, is it safe to distribute the `credentials.json` file (contains client_id, client_secret, project_id) with my app? What are the potential security issues? If this is not suitable, what is the least complicated alternative to make my app distributable safely?**

## Edit

I looked at Google's docs and found [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed).

> The process results in a client ID and, in some cases, a client
> secret, which you embed in the source code of your application. (In
> this context, **the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret**.)

So the client_secret isn't secret in this case, right? What about the rest of `credentials.json`? Can someone impersonate my app and do bad things using that information?

Here's the code (it works) that does the first-time login:

```
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback, method, args) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });

    require('electron').shell.openExternal(authUrl);
    // mini server for authorization

    const express = require('express')()

    //express part
    express.get('/authorize', function (req, res) {
        oAuth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            method(oAuth2Client, callback, args);

        });
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'authorize.html'));
    });

    express.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000`)
    })

}
```

And the function I use to access the API if a token is saved:

```
function ApiCall(method, callback, args) {
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
        var credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        var {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.web;
        var oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

        // Check if we have previously stored a token.
        fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback, method, args);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
            method(oAuth2Client, callback, args);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed#bigquery-enduser-installed-packages-python clearly states "This file must be distributed with your app." yet I am also reluctant to include it in the app.  What if someone takes that file, and uses it for their own app?  Then their API calls will be counted against my quota.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just looking at the google oauth github repo for another project, and came across this:

> If you're authenticating with OAuth2 from an installed application
> (like Electron), you may not want to embed your client_secret inside
> of the application sources. To work around this restriction, you can
> choose the iOS application type when creating your OAuth2 credentials
> in the Google Developers console:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#oauth2-with-installed-apps-electron

Not sure how that prevents another app from using your client ID in the same fashion, but it's their suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe to distribute client secret in this manner as it can be easily exfiltrated out of your app by an attacker. Client id is safe to distribute, on its own it's not enough for an attack. You don't need project id for authorization.

The flow you want to implement is known as authorization code grant type in oAuth. You'll also want to implement a [PKCE extension.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) Taken together, authorization code + PKCE is a recommended approach for using oAuth in a native app running on an end-user's device.

Google [documents](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#server-flow) authorization code without PKCE as "Server Flow" (somewhat of a misnomer) using OpenId Connect. The latter is a superset of oAuth, everything above still applies:

> 1. Create an anti-forgery state token
> 2. Send an authentication request to Google
> 3. Confirm the anti-forgery state token
> 4. Exchange code for access
>    token and ID token
> 5. Obtain user information from the ID token
> 6. Authenticate the user

You may not need steps 5-6 in your application.

You can try rolling steps 1-4 in JS with [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) or you can give [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) a shot.

Comment: Step 1 involves creating a token (which should not be accessible to user, right?), is this done on the end user's computer or on a remote server that I need to set up? I am using the mentioned google-api-nodejs-client package currently with the credentials+token method. How do I implement the PKCE flow with it?

Comment: Step 1 is done on the client and "shared" with the server. PKCE - if you read the RFC and have a look at oidc-client-js source code (they implement it), you should be able to roll from there.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need to set up another server. That's good, but does PKCE prevent a bad actor from using the credentials in another app that does malicious things under my name?

Comment: PKCE is a countermeasure that prevents injection (replay) of authorization codes into the authorization response by attackers in your app.  So yes, you want to implement it.