# Safely Distributing Electron App with Google API Credentials

Tags: electron, google-oauth, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I'm trying to make a simple Electron app for viewing and managing files from different cloud storage services. I've got Drive to work perfectly now, but now I want to use electron-builder to distribute the app. I would like to not have the user go and create their own credentials from Google Cloud, because it's tedious for the user and also doesn't give me the data from the requests

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214809/is-it-safe-to-distribute-google-api-credentials-with-apps) post with the same question as me, but it's 3 years old and one of the answers (claiming that the Google auth library for nodejs said electron apps might want to choose to use iOS application credentials to work around the problem) doesn't have anything to prove the information in the link provided anymore. The other answer suggested implementing authorization code grant type flow with a PKCE extension. Is authorization code + PKCE still the way to go or is there a newer, easier way to do this?

Also, even after looking on Electron's docs, I'm not sure whether I should use electron-builder or electron-forge to distribute the app to multiple platforms, so help with choosing either of those would be appreciated